# find revisiting already visited folder

Tags: find, cygwin

When using below command to list folders as they get deleted

```
$ find . -type d -name .idea -exec sh -c "echo {}; rm -rf {}" \;
    ./.idea
    find: ‘./.idea’: No such file or directory
    ./folder1/.idea
    find: ‘./folder1/.idea’: No such file or directory
$
```

no idea why deleted folders are being revisited by find producing error of

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is find trying to recurse into the folder it just removed?

Comment: `find` visits first the directories and then the content of them. Most likely it precalculates a list of entries to be visited. If you delete a directory with all files inside it, I could imagine that `find` does not notice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` processes each directory's contents after the directory itself.

So you need to add `-depth` option :

```
find . -depth -type d -name .idea -exec sh -c "echo {}; rm -rf {}" \;
```

*Update*

You can do following expriment, first

```
mkdir -p .idea/folder1/.idea
```

```
# Step 1
find . -type d -name .idea -exec sh -c "echo rm -rf {}" \;
# rm -rf ./.idea
# rm -rf ./.idea/folder1/.idea
```

```
# Step 2
find . -depth -type d -name .idea -exec sh -c "echo rm -rf {}" \;
# rm -rf ./.idea/folder1/.idea
# rm -rf ./.idea
```

You can see that in `step 1`, `find` first removes `./.idea` and then tries to search the subdirectories to find `./.idea/folder1/.idea`.

Whereas in `step 2`, `find` first tries to search the subdirectories to find `./.idea/folder1/.idea` and removes `./.idea` after that.

Comment: Does this mean, find does 'rm -rf {}' when there is a match during traversal and 'echo {}' deferred until the traversal is finished? How does adding -depth option help? Shouldn't the order or commands to -exec be preserved, regardless of how traversal happens, breadth first or depth first?